# Android AIDL Service not executing

Tags: java, android, aidl

I use Android Automotive 11 environment, The below code actually also does not run under Regular Android 11 environemnt.

I Use the emulator that I've built from source Android 11 r35.

When I try to open the AIDL service I get the following error:

PermissionMonitor: NameNotFoundException

BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed
[image]

Here is the code:

```
public class MySimpService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new SimpServiceImp();
    }
}
```

SimpServiceImp Class:

```
public class SimpServiceImp extends ISimp.Stub {

    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
        return a+b;
    }

    @Override
    public int sub(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
        return a-b;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AIDLService" >

    <service android:name=".MySimpService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.aidlservice.MySimpService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: AIDL is obsolete.

Comment: Oh good to know, What's the alternative? as to give API to pass data/information between Service and applications.

Comment: Android 11 requires you to explicitly declare intents and packages your app is going to query. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/67114596/9241978

Comment: But my app does not query, My app is the service that expose an API.

Answer (score 1):

There were a lot of basic Android issues which made this not work.
Part of it is Service had to have Notification to keep alive.

https://github.com/NewstHet/AndroidAidlClient
https://github.com/NewstHet/AndroidAIDLService

Github links contains working AIDL service using Android 11 API 30.